# Close a program when finished with command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that open an `.exe` program. The program is `fileuploader.exe`.

Is there a way to close this program when the upload process finished with the command line?

Because the program generate an output file and i need this output for another command line operation.

I tried this:

```
start fileuploader.exe filetoupload  
:loop  
taskkill /im fileuploader.exe   
goto loop
```

When the program is working and `taskkill` send a request to close the program, it shows this message:

> An upload is in progress do you want to exit?

the loop do this until the upload is finished and `taskkill` close Fileuploader. But I don't like this solution.

There's a way to execute the `taskkill` after a certain time? Like every 2 minutes for example?

Comment: you can try with ` fileuploader.exe filetoupload`  only - the command prompt will exit when the upload is finished. To start the seccond script you can use conditional execution


 http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php

Comment: @npocmaka I try this way but the prompt never close, it close only if i manually Press the X button on the Fileuploader Window

Comment: Ok..How did you know if the upload is finished?

Comment: Fileuploader is a Gui Program :)
The problem is that it have no Command Line Option, so I use Fileuploader.exe that open the Program Window, in the program i set the auto upload.
When upload finished appear in tray bar a message "Upload Completed".
I also think to  taskkill the program when the memory usage go under a certain value.
If is not possible to do that in dos, there's a way to do it in Php?

Answer (score 0):

> There's a way to excute the taskkill after a certain time? (like every
>   2 minutes for example?)

You can create a delay with ping command. ping unreachable address once with a desired timeout value (ms). This example will wait 2 minutes before each taskkill.

```
start fileuploader.exe filetoupload  
:loop  
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 120000 >NUL
taskkill /im fileuploader.exe   
goto loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is this method, which gives you a countdown in the title of the window:

```
@ECHO off
TITLE Initial title
SET TITLETEXT=Countdown the uploader
:: start of script
start fileuploader.exe filetoupload  
:loop  
CALL sleepMe 120
taskkill /im fileuploader.exe   
goto loop
:: rest of script
GOTO :END
:: Function
:sleepMe ARG
ECHO Pausing...
FOR /l %%a in (%~1,-1,1) do (TITLE %TITLETEXT% -- time left %%as&PING.exe -n 2 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul)
EXIT /B 0
:END
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

If File&Image Uploader is [here](http://z-o-o-m.eu/), then it may be implemented [on next release](http://forum.z-o-o-m.eu/index.php/topic,3878.msg13797.html#msg13797), else the `ping` solution is the best without additional tool.

On many computers you will find `sleep.exe` from the Windows Resource Kit or Powershell scripts which have an embedded `Start-Sleep`

HTH